# JSON Serialization Issue: The argument type 'Tracks' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter

I have written a custom type "Tracks", and am reading the track from a JSON file and then converting into a List of `<Tracks>`.

Here is a portion of the code (which throws the error on the 4th line):

```
Future loadTrackList() async {
    String content = await rootBundle.loadString('data/titles.json');
    List<Tracks> collection = json.decode(content);
    List<Tracks> _tracks = collection.map((json) => Tracks.fromJson(json)).toList();

    setState(() {
      tracks = _tracks;
    });   }
```

Additionally, here is the tracks.dart file where I have serialized the JSON.

```
class Tracks{   final String title;   final String subtitle;

  Tracks(this.title, this.subtitle);


  Tracks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) :
      title = json['title'],
      subtitle = json['subtitle']; }
```

And in my original usage scenario, I use this list of tracks in this manner:

```
body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: tracks.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        var rnd = new Random();
        var totalUsers = rnd.nextInt(600);
        Tracks trackTitles = tracks[index];
        return PrimaryMail(
          iconData: OMIcons.supervisorAccount,
          title: trackTitles.title,
          count: "$totalUsers active",
          colors: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        );
      },
    ),
```

Now, firstly - in the first bunch of code inside the async loader, I am getting the error error: `The argument type 'Tracks' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.` for the line

`List<Tracks> _tracks = collection.map((json) => Tracks.fromJson(json)).toList();`

Additionally, when I use the track here:

```
title: trackTitles.title, // inside listView builder
```

I get the error (when running the app, not before): `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic is not a subtype of type 'tracks'`

Requesting for any kind of help regarding how to get rid of this issue. You can [find the important part of the whole code in this link](https://gist.github.com/Eshpelin/5528777b5f8192f62fa41bef20556a06) for a good look into the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:news_app/tracks.dart';

class TrackList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TrackListState();
}

class _TrackListState extends State<TrackList> {
  List<dynamic> tracks = List<dynamic>();

  Future loadTrackList() async {
    String content = await rootBundle.loadString('data/titles.json');
    var collection = json.decode(content);
    print(collection);
    List<dynamic> _tracks =
        collection.map((json) => Tracks.fromJson(json)).toList();

    setState(() {
      tracks = _tracks;
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    loadTrackList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: tracks.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              Tracks item = tracks[index];
              return Text(item.title);
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Portions of your code on `class _TrackListState` helped solve the issue. Much appreciated.